# WAF, SCons or did I overlook something

Tags: build-automation, scons, waf

I am looking for a make alternative (for lots of reasons which I will keep to myself for now).

My needs are something that will compile c/c++ and C# and run static analysis and unit tests. It must be easy to grasp, and maintain even for people with intermediate technical skills.

During my analysis, I have fallen for WAF and SCons and especially WAF has impressed me and I plan on testing them tomorrow.

My concern is that I have overlooked some gotcha with these tools or a third or fourth build tool that would fit my needs better.

What is your opinion: did I overlook something?

**Update 20100818** I tried WAF and it solved all of my problems, so I will stay with this tool. My only concern now is how to make it cross compile controlled by LTIB...

Answer (score 1):

The KDE project had some problems with scons, build time were very long (my experience), and there was other issues (i don't really recall which exactly), so CMake was proposed and it's the current build system used by KDE.

This experience might be useful to you.

See http://lwn.net/Articles/188693/ for more information.

Comment: Seems like the main problem in KDE project was bad communication with upstream SCons.